# Batch splitting large files into smaller files

Tags: windows, file-management, ubuntu

I am looking for a program for Microsoft Windows or Ubuntu that can take as input a folder  and splitting in any file larger than some file size threshold  into smaller files. I don't want to have to manually split each large file myself.

Any license and price is fine.

Comment: The obvious question is "What type of files" as some files can be simply split, (e.g. plain text files, csv files, etc), while others, (e.g. exe, zip, jpg, etc.), will not function in any way correctly if split _(unless they are re-joined before use)_.

Comment: @SteveBarnes any type of file. The use case is syncing the files with OneDrive, and OneDrive has a limit of 15GB per file.

Comment: For Ubuntu I think the `split` command can be used as well, together with the `find` command for files larger than a certain size this can be even a one liner. All of course when it has not to be split based on some criteria as `split` is just a binary splitter.

Answer (score 1):

[7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) can archive a file into multiple parts which can be extracted later.

Here is a guide on how to do it: https://www.linglom.com/it-support/how-to-split-a-large-file-using-7-zip/

> 1. Download and install 7-Zip
> 2. Right-click on the file(s) -> Select 7-Zip -> Add to archive
> 3. On Add to Archive, name the archive, select archive format, define file size limit(15GB in your case) and then click OK.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. When finished, you’ll see that a large file is split into new smaller Zip files with size limit as you defined.
> 5. To get the original file from these Zip files, right-click one of these Zip files -> select 7-Zip -> click Open archive.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to have to manually split each large file myself.

Comment: 7zip also has a command line utility

Comment: Sounds like a few lines of Python might be in order